# mod.protocol-pulse: server 0x55660ccbe800: failed to create client: Connection refused

Tags: pulseaudio, 23.04, pipewire

Often, when my PC runs for a while and I try open the PulseAudio volume control panel, it refuses to connect to the PA server, the panel gets stuck at "Establishing connection to PulseAduio. Please wait..." and I can see messages like `pipewire-pulse[2166005]: mod.protocol-pulse: server 0x55660ccbe800: failed to create client: Connection refused` in user service journal. Running `systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service` helps.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into similar issues for the past day. Everything was working as expected, but eventually (after booting), the volume controls weren't working.
When i run `--user status pipewire-pulse`, i get the following error: 
`mod.protocol-pulse: 0x55f87164abd0: failed to connect client: Host is down` 
Which is very similar to yours. But running `--user restart` also didn't work for me.
In my cause, i noticed that the pipeware-pulse was the only one active (pipeware, pulseaudio and wireplumber were all masked)...

---

###### Solution:

- Run `sudo apt reinstall pipewire pipewire-pulse` to reinstall the packages
- Run `systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse` to enable those services

Right after that the controls appear back and the sound comes back to normal.